# Global scope add extra query when access each item attribute in collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have global scope which attach the count number of Model which are related to the Main model, when I try to access it in the view it perform another query

In the main Model I have add the global scope like this

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope("reply_count", function(Builder $builder) {
        $builder->withCount('replies');
    });
}

public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);
}
```

When I try to access `replies_count` in the view like `$model->replies_count` It add another extra query. and the app is performing so many query as I have loop through the collection of `$models`

> 109 statements were executed, 106 of which were duplicated,

Comment: Have you tried the booted method instead of the boot one? Just my wild guess but maybe it works, according to the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#applying-global-scopes

Comment: Yes I tried with the `booted` method, I'm still getting the same issue